# Binary trees- pseudo codes?

Tags: data-structures, pseudocode

I'm trying to write this pseudo code for checking whether a data-structure based on trees 
is a binary tree.

I'm having a little problem with understanding this pseudo code form.

This is what I wrote:

```
Is-Binary(x)    
  if (x=null) {Then Return True
            }
       else {
            if (x.Right<>Null) {Then
                if (x.key<x.right.key){Then
                   Is-Binary(x.Right)}
                else {Return False}}

            if (x.Left<>Null) {Then
               if (x.key>x.Left.key){Then
                  Is-binart(x.Left)}
               else {Return False}}
             }
```

My question: Can I assume that after the first true will be accepted, the program wont finish?

What does the return means here? will it sum up all  the true/false and give the final soulotion (based on the fact that true*false=false?)

If so, what else can I do?

Thank you

Comment: your pseudo-code is suffering from the dangling-else problem... each time there is an `else`, we don't know which `if` it refers to.

Comment: you are not doing anything with the result of isBinary(x.Left) and isBinary(x.right), you should store them in a local variable and verify they are all true..

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: The main aim of pseudo-code is **readability**. Your pseudo-code fails in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only get one result, either true or false, because you're not accumulating anything. Assuming you're starting from the top of a tree, say you only go one level deep, you'll only get true or false as a result. Then, if you get another level deeper (with another call), you're just facing the same possibilities: True, false, or deeper in the tree.

[Edit, after further observation:] Unless I'm mistaken, you'll get True the first time you hit a null, which might never happen because you never call Is-Binary on a null-value.

So if X is null you get true, else you get false.

Comment: I would like to help more, but I don't understand the problem at hand. How do you plan to check if a data structure is a binary tree?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. here's an exmaple for a binary tree:
http://mousely.com/encyclopedia/Binary_tree/

Comment: I understand what a binary tree is, what I don't get is what you're trying to achieve. If you don't know whether it's a binary tree or not, why are you calling left and right? What information are you trying to get out of the data structure?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to check whether is binary tree or not..this is whst I am trying to achieve

Comment: But the definition of a "binary tree" is just a data structure that has a root node with no parent, with each nodes having zero to two child nodes. If your function can walk a binary tree, and expects a binary tree, then how do you check that it's not anything else?